# Python selenium send_keys with array of words

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get Infos from a site with a defined set of keywords (stored in an array), with python selenium action chains. If I pass in my array to the send_keys it throws back an error: 'from invalid argument: 'value' must be a single Unicode code point'. I tried it with passing just a single word to send_keys and it works, but I need to do it with the array of keywords.

ActionChains can handle only single words input and not arrays?

```
keys = ['media', 'image', 'video']

try:
  for key in keys:
    searchbox = driver.find_element_by_id("nav-search") 
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(searchbox)
    actions.click()
    actions.perform()
    actions.send_keys(keys)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    actions.perform()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you want all of the words to be sent at once to send keys?
meaning it would look something like this : send_keys('media image video')
or you wish to send each one from the array and hit return afterwards?

Comment: I wanted to make a loop, so search for each one from the array. I had a previous version without actionchains, but I wanted to implement a click() function, but it works only with actionchains.

Comment: ohh so it looks like you should change 
 actions.send_keys(keys)
to
 actions.send_keys(key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake in your code

your code:

```
keys = ['media', 'image', 'video']

try:
  for key in keys:
    searchbox = driver.find_element_by_id("nav-search") 
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(searchbox)
    actions.click()
    actions.perform()
    actions.send_keys(keys)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    actions.perform()
```

corrected one:

```
keys = ['media', 'image', 'video']

try:
  for key in keys:
    searchbox = driver.find_element_by_id("nav-search") 
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(searchbox)
    actions.click()
    actions.perform()
    #actions.send_keys(keys)
    actions.send_keys(key)
    actions.send_keys(key.RETURN)
    actions.perform()
```

Comment: To avoid such mistakes in future try to use different names for example : ```for key_index in keys :``` liike that, and you'll be prone to make less errors in future

Comment: The place where I've put # means it's a comment cause keys is a list and key is just an iterator variable